# how to avoid "You did not select a file to upload"?

Tags: forms, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I've a form with some inputs and an optional file upload button. Now, whenever i submit the form without uploading the image it gives the error "You did not select a file to upload". I want to avoid this error as i might not always need to upload an image.
Is there anyway to do that?. Thanks in advance. My Controller for adding file is as below:

```
public function add_admin()
{
    $this->data['main_content'] = 'admin/admin_config/index';
    $this->data['sub_content'] = 'admin/admin_config/admin_form';
    $this->load->view(BACKEND, $this->data);
}

public function store_admin()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    unset($post['designation'], $post['password'], $post['re_pass']);
    $post['password'] = sha1($this->input->post('password'));
    $post['designation'] = implode(', ', $this->input->post('designation'));
    $c_pass = sha1($this->input->post('re_pass'));

    $image_name = $_FILES['admin_image'];

    $post['filename'] = $image_name['name'];

    $config = [
        'upload_path' => './upload/admin/',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png',
    ];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($post) {

        if ($post['password'] == $c_pass && $this->upload->do_upload('admin_image')) {
            $this->adminconfig_model->insert($post);
            set_flash('msg', 'Admin added Successfully!!');
            redirect('admin/adminConfig');
        }else{
            $this->data['error_image'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->add_admin();
        }
    } else {
        set_flash('dmsg', 'Password do not match!!');
        $this->add_admin();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's better to share code, always

Comment: please show us your code. Is there a required attribute in your file input

Comment: Sorry for not including the code before. Now i have included it. And there are no require attribute in the file input part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to avoid uploading an image that doesn't exist by checking if the `$_FILES` array is populated. The upload library will always throw that error if no image is uploaded.

You also have some weird logic `if ($post)` will always evaluate to true so we don't really need it. Further it seems like your "wrong password" message is in the wrong place.

The following code will help to fix those errors and clean up your code a bit:

```
public function store_admin() {
    // post stuff
    $data = array(
        'designation' => implode(', ', $this->input->post('designation')),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password')),
        'filename' => ''
    );

    $c_pass = sha1($this->input->post('re_pass'));

    // first check if passwords match
    if ($data['password'] !== $c_pass) {

        set_flash('dmsg', 'Passwords do not match!');
        $this->add_admin();

    } else {

        $upload = true; // general flag, will be overriden with errors should they occur
        // check if image is uploaded
        if (!empty($_FILES['admin_image']['tmp_name'])) {
            $config = [
                'upload_path' => './upload/admin/',
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png',
            ];
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('admin_image')) {
                $upload = $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                // add filename from upload function
                // should do it this way because if overwrite is false
                // upload library will append _1 to the image if it already exists
                $post['filename'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            }
        }

        if ($upload !== true) {
            $this->data['error_image'] = $upload;
            $this->add_admin();
        } else {
            $this->adminconfig_model->insert($data);
            set_flash('msg', 'Admin added successfully!');
            redirect('admin/adminConfig');
        }
    }
}
```